# How to send notification from AsyncTask while main Activity is not started?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have an AsyncTask which starts on boot (called by a service). In some cases I would like to send a notification to start the main Activity. My problem comes when I try to call:

```
NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
```

where eclipse shows me an error because AsyncTask hasn't got getSystemService method. Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `onProgressUpdate` to do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because getSystemService is a method of Context class. Check it out [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29).

Before you call the function, create a Context variable in your AsyncTask. Then initialize it in your constructor, i.e.

```
Context context;

public MyAsyncTask(Context contextin)
{ context = contextin;}
```

Then use this context variable to call your function:

```
NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
```

Do not forget to input your context when you are executing AsyncTask:

```
MyAsyncTask mytask = new MyAsyncTask(getApplicationContext());
mytask.execute();
```

I also have a feeling that an IntentService would be more suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a service that launches your application at the end of the background thread in your asynctask.